# m2e (eclipse) Throwing error after converting to a maven project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I'm trying to convert an eclipse Java project to a Maven project.  When I convert the project to a Maven project, the pom.xml displays the following error:

> Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3.2:runtime
>   Cause: error in opening zip file

When I check the lifecycle file, it's blank.  Any idea of why I can't convert this project without getting this error?

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

If that file is empty, it might have been caused by a bad download of the maven artifact. Therefore check your proxy settings in Eclipse as well as in Maven itself (~/.m2/settings.xml)

Comment: agreed, check with company firewalls if they are stopping you from downloading the maven Zip file

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is deleting the project(from the workspace, not from your computer!) and importing it as a maven project using the deleted project's folder as your source. I've had a lot of trouble in the past with converting projects with m2e, but deleting/re-importing always seems to do the trick.

To import an existing project as a maven project go to file->import and select "Existing Maven Project". Select your project's folder, and import. I realize it's basically the equivalent of "turn it off and turn it on again", but like I said, it has always worked for me in the past. At the very least it will help you narrow your scope.

Hope this helps!